# Scala different parallel structures

Tags: scala, collections, parallel-processing, parallel-collections

I tested parallel collections on Scala vs simple collection, here is my code:

```
def parallelParse()
  {
    val adjs = wn.allSynsets(POS.ADJECTIVE).par
    adjs.foreach(adj => {
      parse(proc.mkDocument(adj.getGloss))
    })
  }

  def serialParse()
  {
    val adjs = wn.allSynsets(POS.ADJECTIVE)
    adjs.foreach(adj => {
      parse(proc.mkDocument(adj.getGloss))
    })
  }
```

The parallel collection speed up about 3 times.
What other option do I have in Scala to make it even faster in parallel, I would be happy to test them and put the results here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use futures to start asynchronous computations. You could do:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
val futures = wn.allSynsets(POS.ADJECTIVE).map(adj => Future {
  parse(proc.mkDocument(adj.getGloss))
})
futures.foreach(f => Await.ready(f, Duration.Inf))
```

Depending on the amount of work on each element in `allSynsets` and the number of elements in `allSynsets` (too many elements -> too many futures -> more overheads), you could get worse results with futures.

To ensure that you are benchmarking correctly, consider using the inline benchmarking feature of ScalaMeter 0.5:

http://scalameter.github.io/home/gettingstarted/0.5/inline/index.html

You could also use actors to achieve this, but it would require a bit more plumbing.

Comment: I used future and the benchmark, but it suddenly reports the time which is incorrect for sure, any idea? Here is the code:
`val time = measure {
      futureParse()
    }
    println(s"Total time future: $time")

 def futureParse()
  {
    wn.allSynsets(POS.ADJECTIVE).foreach(adj => Future {
      parse(proc.mkDocument(adj.getGloss))
    })
  }`

Comment: Sorry, I must have been tired when I was writing the code example. You have to wait for the futures to complete. I've edited my answer to map each element to a `Future`, and then wait until each of the futures completes its work.